# Joining two tables + third table as a conditional column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

If i have three tables called `warehouse` , `warehouse_order` and table called `warehouse_fulfillment`. A warehouse order is created by warehouse admin, initially has 0 fulfillment records, can have many `warehouse_fulfillment` records with failed/rejected statuses, and only one success state (it's done):

```
-- Warehouse
+---------------------------------------+-----------+----------+
| id                                    | name      | location |
+---------------------------------------+-----------+----------+
| 9bcae08e-ad36-4d97-b9ec-4857714e902a  | "big"     | "MLB"    |
+---------------------------------------+-----------+----------+
| b442e783-4725-41e9-af83-f75004ee1b38  | "bigger"  | "MLB"    |
+---------------------------------------+-----------+----------+
| 986d5aa9-0523-42d8-b183-dfd546d3e682  | "biggest" | "MLB"    |
+---------------------------------------+-----------+----------+


-- Warehouse_order Table
+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+----------+
| id                                    | warehouse_id                         |  type  | quantity |
+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+----------+
| 9cb99fd9-9e5e-4240-8162-d28747be01cd  | b442e783-4725-41e9-af83-f75004ee1b38 | BN_100 | 100      |
+---------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+--------+-----------+
| eceb0b5a-5afa-40e4-ac62-efb686e3bdae  | 9bcae08e-ad36-4d97-b9ec-4857714e902a | BN_200 | 400      |
+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+----------+
| 13370467-cf0c-47f2-8fea-a215500607e6  | 986d5aa9-0523-42d8-b183-dfd546d3e68  | BN_300 | 10       |
+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+----------+


-- Warhouse_fulfillment Table
+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+------------+
| id                                    | order_id                              | status     |
+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+------------+
| 8a69edde-2346-48b8-96d0-6c4e25527f38  | 9cb99fd9-9e5e-4240-8162-d28747be01cd  | "FAILLED"  |
+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+------------+
| a2006a64-9bdc-4bfa-ba14-a44769aeb4a2  | 9cb99fd9-9e5e-4240-8162-d28747be01cd  | "REJECTED" |
+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+------------+
| bf0aa1fc-6dfc-4fd0-ba20-be101b1985d1  | 9cb99fd9-9e5e-4240-8162-d28747be01cd  | "FAILED"   |
+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+------------+
| 48c7d747-2f9b-4535-8f27-210a43cf5c30  | 9cb99fd9-9e5e-4240-8162-d28747be01cd  | "SUCCESS"  |
+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+------------+
| 7f8e18c9-4322-428a-9370-9ecd1c5ef286 |  13370467-cf0c-47f2-8fea-a215500607e6  | "FAILED"   |
+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+------------+
```

I want to query the above records in such a way that result looks like so:

```
+--------------------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------+------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
| id                                   | name      | location | order_id                              | order_type | order_quantity | fulfillment_id                       |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------+------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
| 9bcae08e-ad36-4d97-b9ec-4857714e902a | "big"     | "MLB"    | eceb0b5a-5afa-40e4-ac62-efb686e3bdae  | "BN_100"   | 100            | NULL                                 |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------+------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
| b442e783-4725-41e9-af83-f75004ee1b38 | "bigger"  | "MLB"    | 9cb99fd9-9e5e-4240-8162-d28747be01cd  | "BN_200"   | 400            | 48c7d747-2f9b-4535-8f27-210a43cf5c30 |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------+------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
| 986d5aa9-0523-42d8-b183-dfd546d3e682 | "biggest" | "MLB"    | 13370467-cf0c-47f2-8fea-a215500607e6  | "BN_300"   | 10             | NULL                                 |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------+------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
```

I couldn't do this without the repeated rows in cases where an order has multiple failed statuses.

Comment: There is a serious deficiency in the fulfillment table, there should be a timestamp stored with each added status so that you can reliably know the latest status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try SELECT DISTINCT? Because you don't have the status column (which causes the duplicates) in the select list, this should work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT W.id, W.name, W.location, WO.id order_id, WO.type order_type, WO.quantity order_quantity, WF.id fulfillment_id
FROM warehouse W
     LEFT JOIN warehouse_order WO ON W.id = WO.warehouse_id
     LEFT JOIN warehouse_fulfillment WF on WF.order_id = WO.id
```

Otherwise, I would need to know what DBMS the SQL is for, but every flavor I've worked with has some way to rank/order results with a partition so that you can take just the first record based on some key, for example:

```
SELECT id, name, location, order_id, order_type, order_quantity
FROM (
   SELECT W.id, W.name, W.location, WO.id order_id, WO.type order_type, WO.quantity order_quantity, WF.id fulfillment_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WO.id ORDER BY  WF.ID) rNum
FROM warehouse W
     LEFT JOIN warehouse_order WO ON W.id = WO.warehouse_id
     LEFT JOIN warehouse_fulfillment WF on WF.order_id = WO.id
 ) A
 WHERE rNum = 1
```

It would be better to order by date DESC or something like that to get the most recent record.

Answer (score 0):

Without some reliable method within the fulfillment table to determine "latest status", such as a timestamp, you will need to choose some arbitrary method to arrive at a priority order amongst the possible status values. Below I have used a `case expression` within the `over clause` so that "success" will be get the row number 1 if that status exists for an order. Adjust the case expression as you see fit for the other possible values of that column.

When the subquery containing the row number is joined to the main query that join includes `and rn=1` so only fulfillment row per order will be possible.

Please note that in the sample data there is a missing warehouse row so I had to use a left join, but I expect it would be an inner join in the real db.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5f7cd/2)

```
CREATE TABLE Warehouse
    (ID varchar(36), Name varchar(9), Location varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO Warehouse
    ("id", "name", "location")
VALUES
    ('9bcae08e-ad36-4d97-b9ec-4857714e902a', 'big', 'MLB'),
    ('b442e783-4725-41e9-af83-f75004ee1b38', 'bigger', 'MLB'),
    ('986d5aa9-0523-42d8-b183-dfd546d3e682', 'biggest', 'MLB')
;


CREATE TABLE Warehouse_order 
    (ID varchar(36), Warehouse_id varchar(36), type varchar(6), quantity int)
;

INSERT INTO Warehouse_order 
    ("id", "warehouse_id", "type", "quantity")
VALUES
    ('9cb99fd9-9e5e-4240-8162-d28747be01cd', 'b442e783-4725-41e9-af83-f75004ee1b38', 'BN_100', 100),
    ('eceb0b5a-5afa-40e4-ac62-efb686e3bdae', '9bcae08e-ad36-4d97-b9ec-4857714e902a', 'BN_200', 400),
    ('13370467-cf0c-47f2-8fea-a215500607e6', '986d5aa9-0523-42d8-b183-dfd546d3e68', 'BN_300', 10)
;


CREATE TABLE Warehouse_fulfillment 
    (ID varchar(36), Order_id varchar(36), Status varchar(10))
;


INSERT INTO Warehouse_fulfillment 
    ("id", "order_id", "status")
VALUES
    ('8a69edde-2346-48b8-96d0-6c4e25527f38', '9cb99fd9-9e5e-4240-8162-d28747be01cd', 'FAILLED'),
    ('a2006a64-9bdc-4bfa-ba14-a44769aeb4a2', '9cb99fd9-9e5e-4240-8162-d28747be01cd', 'REJECTED'),
    ('bf0aa1fc-6dfc-4fd0-ba20-be101b1985d1', '9cb99fd9-9e5e-4240-8162-d28747be01cd', 'FAILED'),
    ('48c7d747-2f9b-4535-8f27-210a43cf5c30', '9cb99fd9-9e5e-4240-8162-d28747be01cd', 'SUCCESS'),
    ('7f8e18c9-4322-428a-9370-9ecd1c5ef286', '13370467-cf0c-47f2-8fea-a215500607e6', 'FAILED')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
     o.*, w.name, s.status, s.rn
from Warehouse_order o
left join Warehouse w on o.Warehouse_id = w.id
left join (
      select id, order_id, status
          , row_number() over(partition by order_id 
                              order by case when status = 'SUCCESS' then 1
                                            when status = 'FAILED' then 2
                                            when status = 'REJECTED' then 3
                                            else 4 end) as rn
      from Warehouse_fulfillment
      ) s on o.id = s.Order_id and rn=1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5f7cd/2/0)**:

```
|                                   id |                         warehouse_id |   type | quantity |   name |  status |     rn |
|--------------------------------------|--------------------------------------|--------|----------|--------|---------|--------|
| eceb0b5a-5afa-40e4-ac62-efb686e3bdae | 9bcae08e-ad36-4d97-b9ec-4857714e902a | BN_200 |      400 |    big |  (null) | (null) |
| 9cb99fd9-9e5e-4240-8162-d28747be01cd | b442e783-4725-41e9-af83-f75004ee1b38 | BN_100 |      100 | bigger | SUCCESS |      1 |
| 13370467-cf0c-47f2-8fea-a215500607e6 |  986d5aa9-0523-42d8-b183-dfd546d3e68 | BN_300 |       10 | (null) |  FAILED |      1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure on this, but it sounds like you just want a left join on the `order_fulfillment` table with the "success" condition in the join:

```
select
  w.id, w.name, w.location,
  o.id as order_id, o.type as order_type,
  o.quantity as order_quantity,
  f.id as fulfillment_id
from
  warehouse w
  join warehouse_order o on
    w.id = o.warehouse_id
  left join warhouse_fulfillment f on
    o.id = f.order_id and
    f.status = 'SUCCESS'
```

Since you don't seem to care about non-successful records, and there is guarantee that there will only be one 'SUCCESS' fulfillment record, this should avoid any duplicates.

Comment: that won't work. What i need is, if `status` is `success` then return the `order_fulfillment` id , else `null`. This is so that for any given `Warehouse-> Warehouse_order-> Was it fulfilled` i can just look at the return query `fulfillment_id` and if it's null i know it's `either not fulfilled or fulfilment has not succeeded` or if it's populated then i know it was successful.

Comment: That's interesting...  I mocked up your data the way you had it listed, and it did exactly that -- and matched your desired output.  Oh well.  It was worth a shot.